# Multiple sub-domain FormsAuthentication not working, using Web API MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am doing a project which needs a Website and a Mobile app, almost with same functionality.
So for this I am building API using **Asp.net Web API**, which is to be used in Website and Mobile App too.

API address is : api.domain.com
Website address is : testing.domain.com

Problem:

Now at api.domain.com, I am allowing user to log in, **FormsAuthentication** is used there with **Cookies**.

When user get authenticated it gets **200 Http Satus** along with **Set-Cookie** Header, where domains allowed are also mentioned.

Here is the request and response:

```
**Request**

Request URL:http://api.domain.com/account/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:139
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:api.domain.com
Origin:http://testing.domain.com
Referer:http://testing.domain.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fteacherpanel
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Form Dataview URL encoded
__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUKMTY1NDU2MTA1MmRkmpJ4YQ4kteUpklwLOmcHppPgq/RHqfw7tilyk8pJp0Y=
UserName:ishan
Password:pass





**Response**

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Date:Sat, 22 Sep 2012 10:23:38 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie:.Teacher=A3BD94D26CF733F6F223198ADE40D87C76D8ECC663D7CEDD6E3FF18B0ED23032F6089EF24141E0B65F3F29503A3AC1670C92B9CE4EF7D986974ABE61AB5F0C837245D1A30A8D8E8E058F9AFDD89281CBAB9A3EB98B4A320E689718AF9E76E4911506EBA7FD4244336D8409CFB6D77B179764726B550AB0FFF7A6508658615A57; domain=domain.com, .domain.com; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Now according to response, Browser should send this cookie to server with every request to this domain **domain.com** or any **subdomain** of it.

But this is not happening, how ever this morning it work for me, but i don't know what happened after I did an publish.

Also for more refrence here is the code I am using to set cookie and to check if user logged in.

Here to log in user, this check is performing in API, at api.domain.com.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Teacher t;
                if (Teacher.Login(model.UserName,model.Password,out t))
                {
                   // Roles.AddUserToRole(t.ID.ToString(), "teacher");

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(t.ID.ToString(), model.RememberMe);






                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ft = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                     1,                                   // version
                     t.ID.ToString(),   // get username  from the form
                     DateTime.Now,                        // issue time is now
                     DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),         // expires in 10 minutes
                     true,      // cookie is not persistent
                     "teacher"                              // role assignment is stored
                        // in userData
                     );

                    string enTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ft);


                    HttpResponseMessage res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);


                    System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue cokie = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, enTicket);
                    cokie.Domain = "domain.com  .domain.com";
                    IEnumerable<System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue> cookies = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue[] { cokie };

                    res.Headers.AddCookies(cookies);


                    return res;

                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
```

Now at testing.domain.com, simply checking authentication of user according to its Role, at web.config.

```
<location path="TeacherPanel">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="teacher" />
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

These are the detail which I found to be checked researching through this problem. Feel free to suggest any thing, every clue will be helpful.

**Authentication section in web config of testing.domain.com**

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".Teacher" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" domain=".domain.com" />
    </authentication>
```

**Authentication section in web config of api.domain.com**

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms  name=".Teacher"
    cookieless="UseCookies"
    requireSSL="false"
     domain=".domain.com"
     />
</authentication>
```

**After Adding Machine key and Adding Expire time to Cookie**

**Post Request by browser for authentication:**

```
POST /account/login HTTP/1.1
Host: api.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 123
Origin: http://testing.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://testing.domain.com/TeacherLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fteacherpanel
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUKMTY1NDU2MTA1MmRkCjMwS9YdCRDD3Qsd4GYnLj+tGGg=
UserName:username
Password:pass
```

**Response sent by server:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: .Teacher=9C8FD43FABDC1817D21272361CBF798BB64C364DECC62E2F5F666D1B2A248076C67737D89B03F515D4D81524345584B11E206B2DDEAD5AA846A15BC17B32D86DF1C95A2943766AB5955C99A8DD0D5984089131838E158A90241B60D40A2D928086486E2BA3DDE95814E7FA303845FBDE235D69F54B6891852A09A80F7465FF8C59957A4D; expires=Wed, 26 Sep 2012 10:02:46 GMT; max-age=432000; domain=.domain.com; path=/; secure; httponly
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2012 10:02:46 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

**Next Get Request sent to testing.domain.com to test (Which fails because browser not sending cookies back to server) :**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: testing.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://testing.domain.com/TeacherLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fteacherpanel
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

**Any guess why Browser not sending the Cookies Back?**

Comment: Can you also post the <authentication><forms> section of your web.config? Do both API and Testing have a web.config? And if so, have you made sure the machinekey matches?

Comment: Just added <authentication> section, but not sure about machinekey where to find and where to insert?

Comment: added machinekey to answer below

Comment: Check that you don't have a web.config debug transform file that is changing your values.

Answer (score 0):

Two things might be happening here:

1. If you do not have machinekey in both API and Test web.config then you are probably using the inherited settings from the .Net Framework machine.config or web.config. This would be generating different keys per application so the cookie issued in one cannot be decrypted by the other. You should add the same [machinekey section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to each web.config. You can use one of the many online generators such as [this one](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey).
2. Another problem is with trying to put multiple domains in single cookie. Change this line:

   cokie.Domain = "domain.com  .domain.com";

To this:

```
cokie.Domain = ".domain.com";
```

Actually, looking at your  sections you might not even need this line since both of them are set to issue cookie at .domain.com

EDIT: also check the [httpCookies section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228262%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) of your web.config to control whether the cookies are sent with the secure flag set. For example in the development environment you'd want to turn off the secure flag:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
```

There is also the [forms tag requireSSL property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but I don't think that applies in your case because you are manually issuing the cookie.

Comment: Just did the machine key trick, but not working... The problem is.. once browser receives the Cookies, it should have to send with next request, but here its just not sending them.

It seems something is missing which is stoping Browser to send the  Cookie back with next request.

Comment: original question has request/response but can you post what it looks like now after your code/config changes? Also the next request after the original response (the one that doesn't send the cookies)?

Comment: Just got very near to the solution, the problem is the 'expire' Field of cookie is not set, do you have any idea that why server is not sending cookie with setting expire time?? its an IIS7.

Comment: It looks like the cookie has an expire time. However, I see that the secure flag is set on the cookie but the subsequent request is just HTTP. That might be why the cookie is not sent.

Comment: I just added "secure" as an experiment, after that I removed it and it does't work in both ways. 

I was researching and somewhere I found a clue that this problem is may be because of "Cache-Control" header, when I compared this response with the one which is made when we user FormsAuthentication in normal website.

Normal website have Cache-Control:private, no-cache="set-cookie" .

but here it is Cache-Control:no-cache, Seems problem thing to me.

What you think, you have any idea abour "Cache-Control" Header?